# can I use question Mark(?) in querystring for GET request in Servicestack?

Tags: servicestack

I have created services stack, now when i fire GET request
i.e
localhost:123/myRest/ClassName/application/123456789?Count = 10
For above, 
123456789 is the application Id

```
[RestService("/perfmon/application/{applicationId}?Count = 10")]
```

For my application, I got the actual result fine, but the problem is that when i try to check its JSON view, not able to see because it generate URL as below

```
localhost:123/myRest/ClassName/application/123456789?Count = 10?format = json
```

(two questionmark so it is wrong)
When i change it to

```
localhost:123/myRest/ClassName/application/123456789?Count = 10&format = json
```

Can I control this when for ?format=Json.
it gives me JSON output for my data

This happens from the default view. (see below image)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the HtmlFormat that is fixed in the latest version (v3.03) of ServiceStack. Download latest dlls at:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/downloads

Comment: Hey gr8, really without your answer i will never know until i work on next project with new dll

Comment: @amitpatel well it wasn't a co-incidence as I fixed it after you reported it here. So thx for reporting! :)

Comment: I don't mean so that i report you and fix it. I mean I never know until i work on new projects with new dlls. anyway, thanks a lot for your gr8 help, i solve my prob